# Directive in Directive - watch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Spend many hours, tried almost everything , but it doesn`t work ..

I have Angular directive witch call another angular directive ..
I need to handle event in child directive. 
So my child directive look like :

```
           restrict: 'E',
           replace: true,
           scope: {
               testResult: "=",
```

And in parent directive i have :

```
<my-search-directive test-result="newTest"></my-search-directive>
```

To handle changes in testResult , in parent directive i have this watch :

```
  $scope.$watch('newTest', function (newVal, oldVal) {
      alert('test ' + newVal + ' ' + oldVal);
  }, true);
```

It fires only one time in the beginning and newVal and oldVal are undefined.. 
If i have service instead of 'master' directive it works (i`m passing parentScope and use it for watch)

In the beggining newTest was return complex object and i thing that could be the problem , but it`s not ,because it now work with simple string also.

Try to use watchcollection , but it not working also .. I need exactly this scenario , directive that use directive and i can figure it out how can it works ?

```
EDIT 1 :

myApp.directive('parentDirective', [
    "$log", function ($log) {

        return {
            scope: {
                getQueriesUrl: "=",
                isFullyQualified: "=",
                isMainTabs: "=",
                model: "=",
                crudUrls: "=",
                callBackFunction: "&",
                callback: "&",
                newTestResult: "@"
            },
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            controller: function ($scope) 
{
myActions.push('<div><my-search-directive test-result="newTestResult"></my-search-directive></div>');
}
```

That is my 'parent directive' , so i need to track changes of test-result. As @Walfrat mantion , i added newTestResult variable , but still doesn`t work ..

Comment: I have workaround .. ofcouse i can use $rootScope to track changes.. but this is not a solution ..

Comment: Did you find a solution for this without using `$rootScope`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you re not using directive in directive.

You're using a directive with 2 way binding here.

Since your scope is binded to data you should watch `testResult` as defined in your `scope{}` block. If $watch not working try watchCollection on it and you should be fine.

Comment: May you don't underastand my well.. please take a look at section Edit 1 in my question , i think it`s more clear now.. Thank you for your support.

Comment: i see.. first change the `newTestResult:@` to `=` since you have it in your search directive. If this doesn't work, you can add a watch in your parent controller and generate events. Events catch by your search directive. Another way would be to expose an API in your parent directive and use it in your search directive. This is not so easy though

Comment: Thank you , for now i`m using $rootScope .. I know that is bad practice , but i don`t have time for that right now